# The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Tags: asp.net, page-index-changed

I have created:

- one master page and one content page called Detail.
- On Button click event, displaying data in grid view.
- In grid view, columns are autogenerated.
- I wanted to show 11 column in grid view, but it is more than page
  size.

What to do for this?

I have created sql helper file for database connection code and calling that method, not using sqldatasource for connection.

When I trying to do paging, getting **error**:

> The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't
>   handled.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to declare a method on your code behind that handles the PageIndexChanging event.

Something similar to this:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging (object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs  e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindGridView(); //bindgridview will get the data source and bind it again
}

private void bindGridView()
{
     GridView1.DataSource=getData();
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Providing sample code:**

```
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGridView(); //bindgridview will get the data source and bind it again
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
         bindGridView();

    }
    //this is some sample data 
    private void bindGridView()
    {
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add("Col1");
        t.Columns.Add("Col2");
        DataRow r = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            r = t.NewRow();
            r.ItemArray = new object[] { "Val" + i, " Another " + i };
            t.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = t;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And this is the markup:

```
<asp:GridView OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: ya i done that but no effect.  protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //string s1 = "select * from master";
        //DataSet ds = SqlHelper.GetDataSet(CommandType.Text, s1, "master");
        //DataTable table = ds.Tables["master"];

        //if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        //    GridView1.DataBind();
        //}
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        //Bind grid
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
and aspx file

Comment: @JuiTest post this code to your answer, not as a comment. It's more helpful to see it there.

Comment: I can't answer for own question.

Comment: @JuiTest sorry, I meant add this code to your own **question**.

Answer (score 3):

For Paging you can use OnPageIndexChanging for this....

For Example

you have to use **OnPageIndexChanging="gvdetails_PageIndexChanging"** in your GridView...

You have to write below code into event in code behind   like

```
protected void gvdetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvdetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

For more detail you can check the below link here I am using page Index  change in my article...

[**Here I use PageIndexChange**](http://chauhanshekhar.blogspot.in/p/how-to-show-images-in-gridview-from.html)

I hope this will helps you....Share it with others...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the final answer:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic ' library

Protected Sub grdEmployees_PageIndexChanging1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles grdEmployees.PageIndexChanging
    grdEmployees.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    LoadEmployeeList() 'FUNCTION FOR DATASET
    grdEmployees.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you  simply add this to your code :

```
protected void GridViewTrsEmail_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewTrsEmail.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridViewTrsEmail.DataBind();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to take a closer look at my datasource and datakeys. I have a set of records that are returned from SQL Server and what I was doing is binding them to a POCO. This class had several public properties of type Integer. These Integers were my datakeys on the grid. I replaced their type with a string instead to bypass the casting issue.

Comment: This would probably have made a better comment.  It doesn't add much to the accepted answer.